# JQuery Isotope - containing div's height get set to 0px on load (so cant see the images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I have set up the JQuery Isotope plugin as such:

```
$(function(){
$('#isotopecontainer').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.frontitem',
        sortBy: "random",
        masonry : {
        }
 });
});
```

With my HTML:

```
<div id="isotopecontainer">
  <img src="image1.jpg" class="frontitem">
  <img src="image2.jpg" class="frontitem">
  <img src="image3.jpg" class="frontitem">
  ~
</div>
```

But the images only appear once the browser has been resized. Am I missing a step to trigger the images once the browser loads?

I have noticed when I look in the console, Isotope gives the #isotopecontainer div a height of 0px; so none of my images show. This changes when I resize the browser window.

Comment: Running into the same exact problem since 2 days, and i really can't find why. If someone knows...
(resizing doesnt change this for me)

I think this is because we load isotope before loading the content to the page. Not sure